# MicrosoftAjax.js error missing } after function body

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I am building a site in asp .net 2.0 web forms.

When I load up the page firebug gives me the error:

missing } after function body
createCallback()("")
//]]>\n

It's in a file called MicrosoftAjax.js

What might be causing this?

**UPDATE**
I've done a bit more digging and it looks like the problem is coming from the ajaxtoolkit, specifically the AutoCompleteExtender.

When I strip the page back such that the only javascript for the page is the extender. I'm not sure if this is related, but the extender is on a textbox that is in a row of a gridview.

I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any of your own custom javascript?  Try removing it and see if you are still getting the error message.

Comment: Essentially that was the problem. I was injecting some JavaScript into a page, but I had forgotten to close the curly braces. The problem was actually in a different page and on a completely different line. Nothing to do with MicrosoftAjax.js

Answer (score 0):

IE's jscript engine gets very confused if you leave a trailing "," in a list e.g., {a,b,} will create compile errors at locations that have nothing to do with the where the error is.  Following Bendewey's is the best course of action - divide and conquer to find the line with the problem.

I assume firebug is using the same jscript engine as IE does.  FF and Chrome don't have this problem so that's an additional symptom.